# Understanding the ViewHolder pattern

Tags: android, listview, recycle

I created an adapter for a ListView which has two types of rows. The ListView has 4 rows. The last row has a different layout, that's why i use the GetItemViewType method in getview

I'm trying to understand how the pattern works. I watched this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWsWe9T9HJw to get a better understanding of
how recycling works

What i don't understand is: when i scroll down in my listview, the convertview 
is always null. When i scroll back up again, the convertview is not null and is reusable.

Shouldn't convertview be null only for the first item in the list? i don't get why 
it is null for each new item?

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        BaseBundelVO bundle = _bundles [position];

        DSBundleListItem bundleHolder = null;
        DSBundleArchiveItem archiveHolder = null;

        int type = GetItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            bundleHolder = new DSBundleListItem (_activity);
            archiveHolder = new DSBundleArchiveItem (_activity);

            switch (type) 
            {
            case 0:
                convertView = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.dsBundleListItem, null);
                bundleHolder.IconIv = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.iconIv);
                bundleHolder.CoverIv = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.coverIv);
                bundleHolder.CoverTitleTv = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.coverTitleTv);
                bundleHolder.CoverSubTitleTv = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.coverSubTitleTv);
                bundleHolder.BundleProgress = convertView.FindViewById<ProgressBar> (Resource.Id.bundleProgress);
                convertView.Tag = bundleHolder;
                break;
            case 1:
                convertView = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.dsBundleArchiveItem, null);
                archiveHolder.ArchiveTitleTv = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.archiveTitleTv);
                archiveHolder.ArchiveSubTitleTv = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.archiveSubTitleTv);
                convertView.Tag = archiveHolder;
                break;
            }

        } 
        else 
        {
            switch (type) 
            {
            case 0:
                bundleHolder = (DSBundleListItem)convertView.Tag;
                Console.WriteLine (bundleHolder.IsDisposed ());
                bundleHolder.RemoveImageLoaderCallBack ();
            break;
            case 1:
                archiveHolder = (DSBundleArchiveItem)convertView.Tag;
                Console.WriteLine (archiveHolder.IsDisposed ());
                archiveHolder.RemoveImageLoaderCallBack ();
            break;
            }
        }

        switch (type) 
        {
        case 0:
            bundleHolder.CoverTitleTv.Text = bundle.Title;
            bundleHolder.CoverSubTitleTv.Text = bundle.SubTitle;
            bundleHolder.LoadImage(bundle.CoverImageLocation,bundle.Icon);
            break;
        case 1:
            archiveHolder.ArchiveTitleTv.Text    = "Archief";
            archiveHolder.ArchiveSubTitleTv.Text = "Bekijk onze eerder verschenen publicaties";
            break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: If your screen can fit say 2 views, then android will load the view up, the 2 visibile views, and the next view at the bottom, So it needs at least 4 views.This explains why it isn't just the first convertview null. Btw FIY you should check the new RecyclerView with Api 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't convertview be null only for the first item in the list?

Not usually.

Let's suppose that that 8 rows are visible in the `ListView`. That means the `ListView` will call `getView()` at least 8 times with `null` for the `convertView` parameter, to populate the visible space in the `ListView`.

`ListView` may also cache a few additional rows, to be able to rapidly respond to scrolling events, as a cache.

Plus, in your case, there are separate object pools maintained for each view type.

If your adapter has enough stuff in it, though, eventually you will recycle even during the initial scroll down. It all depends on the size of the rows, the values that the adapter returns from `getCount()`, etc.

And note that this has nothing really to do with the view holder pattern.

Comment: I tried adding more items to the list and now they get recycled, so this means you were right about the adapter recycling after a certain amount of allocated memory

Answer (score 0):

The `View` that is passed to you in this method is the actual `View` that is displayed in the list (or `null` if it needs you to create one).

If your list is tall enough to show 6 items, for instance, it does need to have at least 6 instances at its disposal!
When you scroll however, one `View` gets out of the window, and can be reused for the other side of the list.

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: i don't understand that when a row goes out of the window on the top of the list, it doesn't get reused when i'm scrolling down. the list items have a large height and only 2 are always visible on the screen